# background opacity in IE8 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

[image]

Here i have 2 images with IE8 and IE9.Below is my code

```
.ui-widget-content { border: 0px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ;     /*{bgColorContent}*/ url(images/scroll.png)/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 0/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 0/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/; color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/;  border-top: solid 1px #FF0000;}
.ui-widget-content a { color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/; }
```

background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ; this is working fine in IE9 but its not working in IE8.Please help how to fix this Issue

Comment: try this one: filter: alpha(opacity=10);

Comment: IE8 doesn't support that natively, you need to use the proprietary `filter` property to achieve that.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

```
img{
 opacity:0.4;
 filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`rgba()` doesn't work on IE8 so you could use

```
filter:alpha(opacity=10);
```

to emulate a 0.1 opacity. 
but this applies the opacity even on the text contained in the element (and to its children, if any) so you may instead apply a repeated small 24-bit `png` image (totally black and the opacity set to `10%`) as a background of your element, e.g.

```
background: url(black-transparent.png)
```

---

(here the image — 50x50, 166bytes — if you need it)
[image: 10% opaque black]

or, if you prefer, here the base64 encoding of the same image (so you save a request)

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAEhJREFUeNrszzERACAMALEHGfUvFBcMvcRBTjUtcFtCRERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERERE5I8nwADPFwB+fDlyvAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

Answer (score 1):

Google is your friend.

```
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Netscape */
-moz-opacity: 0.5;

/* Safari 1.x */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Good browsers */
opacity: 0.5;
```

Taken from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Answer (score 0):

RGBA don't work in IE8 and previous, you must use `filter:alpha(opacity=XX)` as a hack for IE:

```
.ui-widget-content { 
  border: 0px solid #aaaaaa; 
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)  url(images/scroll.png) 0 0 repeat-x; 
  *filter:alpha(opacity=10);/*For pre-IE8 MS browsers*/
  color: #222222;  
  border-top: solid 1px #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had added this code in global.asax file its working fine in IE8 also

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge, Chrome=1");

```
    }
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to replace RGBA on older browser.

Here is a good RGBA to ARGB convertor with older browser support: http://beijingyoung.com/articles/rgba-argb-converter/

```
background: #FFFFFF !important; /* the background */
-moz-opacity: 0.6; /* Mozilla 1.6 and below   */
opacity: 0.6; /* newer browser and CSS-3 */
-ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=60) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99FFFFFF,endColorstr=#99FFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
filter: alpha(opacity=60) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99FFFFFF,endColorstr=#99FFFFFF); /* IE6 & 7 */
zoom: 1;
```